# JQuery UI slider shows wrong value when dragged to 100 (shows 0)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a JQuery UI slider and using both change and slide events. Problem is when adding the slide event and dragging the slider to 100 the value shows as 0 not 100.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrNX8/524/

```
var total;
var s = $("#slider").slider({
  value: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: 500,
  step: 100,
  change: function(event, ui) {
    $('#select').val(s.slider('value'));
  },
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $('#select').val(s.slider('value'));
  },
});
$('#up').click(function() {
  s.slider('value', s.slider('value') + s.slider("option", "step"));
  $('#select').val(s.slider('value'));
});

$('#down').click(function() {
  s.slider('value', s.slider('value') - s.slider("option", "step"));
  $('#select').val(s.slider('value'));
});

$('#select').change(function() {
  s.slider('value', $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Try changing `value: 0,` to `value: 100,`

Comment: Why should it start at `100` when it's value is set to `0` ?

Comment: Sorry I have mispresented the issue. The issue is that when dragging the slider the slider starts with a value of 0 when it should be 100. I edited the original post also.

Comment: If the issue is that the value displayed is always "one step behind" as you slide, then it's because the `slide` event fires *before* the value has changed so that your code can cancel the slide if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide)

> Triggered on every mouse move during slide. The value provided in the
>   event as ui.value represents the value that the handle will have as a
>   result of the current movement. Canceling the event will prevent the
>   handle from moving and the handle will continue to have its previous
>   value.

value of the slider doesnt change during slide, you can access currently selected value via `ui.value`:

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#select').val(ui.value);
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yc349jd/)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when the `slide` event is fired, the value hasn't actually changed yet, which means that `s.slider('value')` is still zero when you set it.

Use the value that is passed to the `slide` callback rather than the value current set on the slider. In other words, you should change `s.slider('value')` to `ui.value` inside of the `slide` callback:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/tsh1weee/)

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#select').val(ui.value);
},
```

Reference: jQuery UI [`slide( event, ui )`](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide)